# .call() a Self-Invoking Anonymous Function,

Tags: javascript

```
// a self-invoking anonymous function
(function() {})();
```

Is it the same as the following?

```
// as in underscore.js (underscorejs.org)
(function() {}).call(this);
```

Comment: They're not, but it all depends on whether you refer to `this` inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the second one will set the calling context of the function to the same value as the outer context.

The first one may or may not have the same context, depending on where this code is run, and whether or not your code is running in strict mode.

Comment: @ianpgall: The default `this` value of a function is `undefined` instead of `window` when you're in strict. Also, if you set a primitive value for `this`, it doesn't cast it to its Object wrapper.